# Force Javascript executing when an error is catched

Tags: javascript, google-api

Sometimes some (non critical) errors come out during the executing of my Javascript code.

While I'm aware that a workaround is not the best solution, I'm stuck on a blocking error which I need to get rid of.

Since the error is basically **can't read [0] of undefined** (the array doesn't exist), what I'd like to is something like:

```
try{
    var abc = array[0];
} catch(e){
   // continue execution
   // skip to the end of this function
   // run a different a function [e.g. alternativeFunction()] 
   // ignore the error
}
```

the **try...catch** block works, it prints the error but my Javascript code is being blocked.

Comment: Why not check if the array exists first? And why is the `try-catch` not working for you?

Comment: I think if you check the array's existence there is no need for the try-catch block. Simply if (array) { var abc=array[0] } will do the trick

Comment: There really are not too many ways to block JS code execution... are you sure there is not some other error that has caused the code to stop executing?

Comment: If the code is your actual code, add check on array being not null and appropriate length as suggested in above comments. If it is sample code and you actually want non-blocking error handler, use the js setTimeout function in the catch block to run another function in background.